# Getting decoded results in terminal after scraping web pages' titles in foreign language

Tags: python, unicode

`enter code here`If you run the program below scraping the web pages' titles in Japanese, I get the results that are not decoded. Could you lend me your hand to get the results in the right language?

(My terminal is set utf-8.)

```
# coding: UTF-8
import codecs
import sys
import urllib
import re

urls = ["http://docs.python.jp/2/howto/regex.html", "http://docs.python.jp/2/library/urllib.html", "http://docs.python.jp/2/library/re.html"]
i = 0
regex = "<title>(.+?)</title>"
pattern = re.compile(regex)

while i< len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    titles = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)

    print titles
    i +=1
```

If I run this file, I get these:

```
['\xe6\xad\xa3\xe8\xa6\x8f\xe8\xa1\xa8\xe7\x8f\xbe HOWTO &mdash; Python 2.7ja1 documentation']
['20.5. urllib \xe2\x80\x94 URL \xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x82\x88\xe3\x82\x8b\xe4\xbb\xbb\xe6\x84\x8f\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x83\xaa\xe3\x82\xbd\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x81\xb8\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x82\xa2\xe3\x82\xaf\xe3\x82\xbb\xe3\x82\xb9 &mdash; Python 2.7ja1 documentation']
['7.2. re \xe2\x80\x94 \xe6\xad\xa3\xe8\xa6\x8f\xe8\xa1\xa8\xe7\x8f\xbe\xe6\x93\x8d\xe4\xbd\x9c &mdash; Python 2.7ja1 documentation']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that the re.findall function returned a list. And by printing the list, your encoding is lost. Here is a quick fix:

```
import codecs
import sys
import urllib
import re

urls = ["http://docs.python.jp/2/howto/regex.html", "http://docs.python.jp/2/library/urllib.html", "http://docs.python.jp/2/library/re.html"]
i = 0
regex = "<title>(.+?)</title>"
pattern = re.compile(regex)

while i< len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    titles = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)

    print titles[0]
    i +=1
```

I added titles[0]

And the result are :

```
正規表現 HOWTO &mdash; Python 2.7ja1 documentation
20.5. urllib — URL による任意のリソースへのアクセス &mdash; Python 2.7ja1 documentation
7.2. re — 正規表現操作 &mdash; Python 2.7ja1 documentation

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: Yes, but why?   It would be good to know why python choses sometimes to print the decoded string, and sometimes to print the encoding?

Comment: @GreenAsJade I am not sure if Python 3 will handle this situation better. But in Python 2 I will do my own conversion every time if I want to output something that is not originally stored in string.

Comment: Thank you, JimmyK and GreenAsJade. I got results in Japanese.
So we need to do the conversion every time..